# Rigid Body settings not copying

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to create a keva plank animation. The first section works fine but when I duplicate it to make the tower higher, and copy rigid body settings, the second half is still fixed - see animation below.

Please could someone suggest what I might have done wrong?

Thanks.
Andrew.

[image: demo]

Comment: Did you bake your simulation and then duplicate? In that case, you need to free the bake and simulate again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no I didn't bake the simulation, and the bake option is still available so I haven't done it by accident.

Comment: I have simplified it in a new project and it does the same -

1. Create plane below default cube and Add Passive to it.
2. Add Active to default cube.  
3. Animation shows cube falling correctly.
4. Copy cube with ctrl+c ctrl+v and drag new cube next to it.
5. Animation shows second cube stationary, even though physics options are the same!
6. Highlight both cube and select default cube and Copy from Active has no effect.

Please can someone tell me what I'm missing? I can't find anyone with the same issue on the web or on youtube videos. I have even tried changing Blender version.

Comment: Problem solved - used Ctrl+D to duplicate instead.

Comment: Ctrl+D is not a short cut for duplicate. Alt + D, and Shift + D are, not sure what you meant here.

Comment: Apologies my mistake, I meant Alt + D